# Overcoming performance issues with background-image for thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webapp that allows users to take and upload a variable number of photos. It is designed to be offline first since users may not have cell coverage or wifi when using it. I'm currently base64 encoding the pictures they take and storing them both in an in-memory array and persisting them to IndexedDB.

To render the images in the UI, I take the base64 encoded image and use it as a data-url for the background-image property in CSS.

This works fine, except initially rendering the page can take several seconds if the user has uploaded a few large images. It seems like the issue is the data-url.

Since the images do not exist on a server, is there any way to address the performance issues of data-urls client side?

How I'm getting the data-url and rendering it:

```js
{
    const file = this.input.files[0];
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      this.input.value = "";
      this.thumbnail.style["background-image"] = `url(${reader.result})`;
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

This is a simplified snippet. I also store the result and when the user refreshes I do something like this:

```js
for(const image of images) {
  this.thumbnail.style["background-image"] = `url(${image})`;
}
```

Is there a more performant way to render images from an in-memory array?

Comment: Short of a better answer, my next plan of attack is to use a Service Worker to persist the image with a UUID and return it from there as a `src="./[UUID].png"`. Will report back on how well that works.

Answer (score 1):

Photos taken on modern mobile devices can be huge. My phone takes 4032x3024 photos by default, and converting 12 million pixels to base64, then reading that data back is a pretty resource-intensive task.

If you’re using it for thumbnails, you could draw each photo to a smaller `<canvas>` with [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). You could draw to a 400x300 canvas, or whatever thumbnail size you need. Then you can convert that smaller image to base64 with [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). It would save you a lot in storage and processing, rather than saving the original image directly to the IndexedDB.